# Python: Implement a complex character logic operation

Tags: python-3.x

What I want to do is as below, like logic operations:

#### Input - Output

```
##input is string and output is character(A or B or C)
## pre-condition: 'A' < 'B' < 'C'

'A and B'                  -->    'B'
'A or B'                   -->    'A'
'A and B and C'            -->    'C'
'(A or B) and C'            -->    'C'
'A and (B or C)'           -->    'B'
'(A and B) or (B and C)'    -->    'B'
...
...
...
```

Any good ideas to implement this? Thanks!!!

Comment: What's the logic behind this table?

Comment: The boolean operators in Python behave exactly like this, you only need to parse the expression from the string first.

Comment: @rdas
The Open Source Software license categories based on GPL:
For example, the license of libksba8 is "(LGPL-3.0+ or GPL-2.0+) and GPL-3.0+ and MIT", I want to get a category(A is GPLv1 or GPLv1-like, B is GPLv2 or GPLv2-like, C is GPLv3, choose the min), so it is "(C or B) and C and A"

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, but the boolean operators are two: 0 and 1, I have three here: 0, 1, 2?

Comment: If you have a finite number of such rules, better just create a lookup table.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “0, 1, 2”. The boolean operators are `and` and `or`.

Comment: Maybe you can try `eval` function? And you'd better pass a `dict` as the `globals` parameter. For example,`eval("(A or B) and C",{"A":"A","B":"B","C":"C"})` returns `"C"`

Comment: @Tianbo Ji  The result is wrong...

`C and A ` returns `'A'`, should be `'C'`,  `C and B` returns `'B'`, should be `'C'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. Finally, I used complicated functions to implement it.

Code:

```
def char_logic_operation(formula_str):
    ## convert str_formula to list, then make a logic operation
    formula_list = re.findall('\([^\)]*\)|\S+', formula_str)
    formula_list = [i.strip('\(\)').split() if re.match('\([ABC] (and|or) [ABC]\)', i) else i for i in formula_list]
    return nesting_list_logic_operation(formula_list)

def nesting_list_logic_operation(n_list):
    #n_list means nesting list
    if any(isinstance(x, list) for x in n_list):
        for i,v in enumerate(n_list):
            if isinstance(v, list):
                n_list[i] = simple_list_logic_operation(v)
        return nesting_list_logic_operation(n_list)
    else:
        return simple_list_logic_operation(n_list)

def simple_list_logic_operation(s_list):
    #s_list means simple list
    if len(s_list) == 1:
        return s_list[0]
    elif len(s_list) >= 3:
        if s_list[1].lower() == 'and':
            res = max(s_list[0], s_list[2])
        elif s_list[1].lower() == 'or':
            res = min(s_list[0], s_list[2])
        del s_list[:3]
        s_list.insert(0, res)
        return simple_list_logic_operation(s_list)
```

Test:

```
>>> str1='A and B'
>>> str2='A or B'
>>> str3='A and B and C'
>>> str4='(A or B) and C'
>>> str5='A and (B or C)'
>>> str6='(A and B) or (B and C)'
>>> char_logic_operation(str1)
'B'
>>> char_logic_operation(str2)
'A'
>>> char_logic_operation(str3)
'C'
>>> char_logic_operation(str4)
'C'
>>> char_logic_operation(str5)
'B'
>>> char_logic_operation(str6)
'B'
```